# Cascading a filter with itself to form a higher-order filter?

Tags: lowpass-filter, denoising

I've been given an audio signal with some high frequency noise. The professor gave me the system function of a lowpass filter that gives me control over the cutoff frequency:

$$H(z)=\frac{1-\alpha}{2}\frac{1+z^{-1}}{1-\alpha z^{-1}}$$

where $\alpha=\frac{1-\sin \omega_c}{\cos \omega_c}$ and $\omega_c$ is the cutoff frequency in radians/sec.

The professor claims that if the filter is cascaded with itself $L$ times, it becomes a filter of order $L$.

My questions are the following:

1. What does increasing the order of the filter do?
2. Why would I want to increase the order of the filter?
3. If I cascade the filter with itself $L$ times, won't I lose the ability to control the cutoff frequency? How could I correct for this?

edit:

Here's what I get for the frequency response of the filter when the cutoff frequency is set to 1000 Hz. Sampling frequency is 16000 Hz.

[image]

Comment: Hi! very nice question. Do you have access to signal processing software Matlab or Octave ?

Comment: @Fat32 Yes, MATLAB is what I am using.

Comment: Have you looked at the frequency response of that 1st order filter ?

Comment: @Fat32 yes, I added a picture

Comment: Now that what remains is to look at the frequency response after cascading the filter with itself. Particularly focus on the first half of the plot (0,4kHz)

Comment: @Fat32 when I cascade it with itself, the curve looks exactly the same, but the attenuation is amplified across all frequencies. this also causes my -3dB frequency to change from ~1000 Hz to 647 Hz

Comment: yes you are right. If you define the cutoff frequency as the -3 dB point wrt to the origin $|H(0)|$ magnitude (which is 0 dB for all orders), then the -3dB point is moving to the DC as the order is increasing. You have probably misunderstood something about the filter or the cutoff frequency. As a rule, when the order is increased the filter becomes steeper, you can see this if you plot the two curves **on** the same y-axis scale..

Comment: @Fat32 great teaching effort

Comment: The result looks like [this](https://ibb.co/d7cuL0)

Comment: @Fat32 so then my cascade is working as it should be? why would I cascade if it sacrifices my ability to set the cutoff frequency?

Comment: Generally speaking, high order filters possess better frequency selectivity by more steeper transition bands and aggressive stop band attenuation.  May be you can find a relation between cutoff frequencies of the cascade orders ?

Comment: @user50420 As Fat32 says, you don't lose the ability to set the cutoff frequency, you just need to figure out how to calculate it. Hint: if one filter stage has gain $|G_0|$ at frequency $f_0$, two cascaded stages will have gain $|G_0|^2$ at the same frequency.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your $\alpha$ with the following to see if it helps:

```
fs = 16000;
fc = 3500;
wc = 2*pi*fc/fs;

L = 5;            % order of the cascade
B = 2^((L-1)/L);
C = cos(wc);
M = B-C-1;
N = 1+C-B*C;
alfa = ( -N + sqrt( N*N - M*M ) )/M;
```

I've got the following plots, compared to your posted $\alpha$ calculation.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The filter has one kernel, and adding L filters (in series) makes the input of the first filter appear convolved, L times, with the same kernel, and repeated convolution leads to a Gaussian response. It's no different than synchronous tuned filters.

If you'd want to increase the order then you'd, most probably, need a steeper rolloff, tighter attenuation, better ripple (if there's the case), etc. In this case, repeating the same stage over and over again, does not achieve these for the fact mentioned above.

As for the ability to control fc, not much you can do about it *this way*, only by properly calculating the filter to be of a higher order, which starts with imposing the design requirements, first, and see where that leads you. Not designing a basic filter for a given set of parameters, then repeatedly placing it over and over again. This is just the professor's way of making you think outside the box.